PHP DLL Extensions not loading - "The specified module could not be found"
I downloaded the pdo_ibm and ibm_db2 extensions for PHP and have placed them in the /ext folder (as .dll for Windows). After that, I go to php.ini and add the following lines (without the ';'):
extension=ibm_db2
extension=pdo_ibm

After trying to run any program, or doing a simple php -v, the following messages are displayed:
C:\Users\jzafrilla\Desktop\xampp\php>php -v

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ibm_db2' (tried: \Users\jzafrilla\Desktop\xampp\php\ext\ibm_db2 (The specified module could not be found.), \Users\jzafrilla\Desktop\xampp\php\ext\php_ibm_db2.dll (%1 is not a valid Win32 application.)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ibm_db2' (tried: \Users\jzafrilla\Desktop\xampp\php\ext\ibm_db2 (The specified module could not be found.), \Users\jzafrilla\Desktop\xampp\php\ext\php_ibm_db2.dll (%1 is not a valid Win32 application.)) in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_ibm' (tried: \Users\jzafrilla\Desktop\xampp\php\ext\pdo_ibm (The specified module could not be found.), \Users\jzafrilla\Desktop\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_ibm.dll (%1 is not a valid Win32 application.)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_ibm' (tried: \Users\jzafrilla\Desktop\xampp\php\ext\pdo_ibm (The specified module could not be found.), \Users\jzafrilla\Desktop\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_ibm.dll %1 is not a valid Win32 application.)) in Unknown on line 0

PHP 7.2.34 (cli) (built: Oct  1 2020 10:24:14) ( ZTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x64 )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies

After checking a phpinfo(); file, they don't appear as activated modules/extensions, nor when I type php -m into the cmd.
Have tried adding the lines to php.ini-production and php.ini-development. Have also tried to change the extension_dir bit in the php.ini file, to absolute and dynamic routes, but still, it doesn't find them. I have checked that the .dlls are for this php version (7.2.34). I don't have any other php instance installated, since the path at the phpinfo() page shows the correct route. Yes, after every change I do restart both XAMPP and the php localhost server to see if it works, but the errors are displayed even while everything is turned off. Any clues?

Are they 32 or 64-bit DLLs?

fyi, php.ini-production and php.ini-development will never be used, those are "template" files that should be renamed/copied to php.ini (depending on if you're in a development or production environment)

In addition, the question lacks precision, what exactly did you download (i.e. the file names)?  Did you also add clidriver as required by the readme (or do you have a separate Db2 client on the PATH etc)?  To which platform of Db2 are you trying to connect (i.e. mainframe Z/OS,  i-series,  linux/unix/windows/cloud )? That should be in the question, it influences what actions you need to take.

@Olivier I believe they are 32 bits, for example, one of them was downloaded from here:  PECL

@brombeer Thanks! I don't play on using them, it was due to pure desperation, but I'll keep it in mind :)

@mao I downloaded the pdo_ibm and ibm_db2 driver files since I am in need to connect to a database with Laravel, using IBM DB2. Here is another page I have downloaded the dlls from, not just pecl.php.net. Have swapped them in an out, none work.
As for the clidriver, I have no clue, I'll look into it right now

ZTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x64 indicates that your PHP is 64 bit, so using 32-bit DLLs won't work.

If your PHP is x64 (as suggested by your question, via text PHP 7.2.34 (cli) (built: Oct  1 2020 10:24:14) ( ZTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x64)`, then you must use the x64 version of the wrappers (php-ibm-db2) and additionally you must use an x64 version of clidriver (or other Db2 client ).

@Olivier Well that does make a lot of sense. I'll try to see if I can find 64-bits DLLs, thank you

@mao Yeah, I ain't the smartest, thank you, I'll try to check the x64 bit DLLs. Will also look out for the x64 version of the clidriver.

@Olivier You were right, right from the start. I couldn't use the 64x drivers nor find them, but downgrading the php version for this small project was the answer. Everything else was already in order, it was just the mismatch from 32 to 64 bits. If you wanna quote your answer I could point it as the right one. Thanks again everyone

The error message:

\Users\jzafrilla\Desktop\xampp\php\ext\php_ibm_db2.dll (%1 is not a valid Win32 application.)

actually means that there is an architecture mismatch between PHP and the DLL (32 vs 64 bits).
Your PHP is compiled as a 64-bit binary, so it will only work with 64-bit extensions.
